# Trying to run an Unturned server

Tags: server, games, steam

[image: screenshot]

So I am trying to run an [Unturned server](https://unturned.fandom.com/wiki/Hosting_a_Dedicated_Server) on my Ubuntu-computer. I installed steamcmd and the server files but when I try to run the .sh file it doesn't work and shows these errors:

> ./ServerHelper2.sh: No such file or directory
>
> cp: cannot stat 'linux64/steamclient.so: No such file or directory
>
> ./Unturned_Headless_.x86_64: No such file or directory

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4
And I am following these instuctions.
I would be greatful for help.

Comment: _these instructions_ from where? What's the web link where those instructions are?

Answer (score 0):

Install Unturned.

Go to the install folder, right click and press open in terminal.

```
./Unturned.x86_64 -nographics -pei -normal -nosync -pve -players:16 -sv
```